# Issue with LaTeX Table Formatting in IEEE Conference Template

Tags: tables, ieeeconf

Hello Tex StackExchange community,

I am encountering an issue with LaTeX while attempting to create a table using the IEEE conference template. As depicted in the first image attached, the table is not displaying as intended. I am aiming for the format shown in the second image.

Here is a snippet of the code I am using:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Research questions for review}
  \label{exp}
  \begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{ @{} LL @{} }
    \toprule
    \#  & Questions                                                                                                                                                                  \\
    \midrule % optional, feel free to omit
    RQ1 & How does SOA contribute to green computing in data centers, focusing on energy efficiency and sustainability?                                                              \\
    RQ2 & What are the most effective SOA-based strategies for reducing electricity usage and carbon footprint in data centers, while maintaining performance?                       \\
    RQ3 & How do green computing techniques integrate with SOA to achieve sustainability goals in data centers, and what challenges and opportunities arise in their implementation? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to rectify this issue and achieve the desired table format?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Image 1:
[image]

Image 2: [image]

Comment: Just change `{ @{} L L @{} }` to `{ @{} l L @{} }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `X` column specification from `tabularx`:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Research questions for review}\label{exp}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ lX } % <-- \columnwidth is also okay here, but \linewidth is more general
    \toprule
    \#  & Questions  \\
    \midrule % optional, feel free to omit
    RQ1 & How does SOA contribute to green computing in data centers, focusing on energy efficiency and sustainability?                                                              \\
    RQ2 & What are the most effective SOA-based strategies for reducing electricity usage and carbon footprint in data centers, while maintaining performance?                       \\
    RQ3 & How do green computing techniques integrate with SOA to achieve sustainability goals in data centers, and what challenges and opportunities arise in their implementation? \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Besides, if you add `@{}`, the margin at both sides of the table will be removed. IMHO, it does not look good in that way.

Comment: Thank you, the code u provided is working.